# Stick First & last | Left & right column in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, sticky

Is it possible to make first and last column of a html table stick and middle columns to be scrollable? (Its possible in Jquery Data tables, but in simple html table?)

Answer (score 0):

**No** - a table in HTML is one entity.

**But** you can do the following:

- Split your table in 3 DIVs.
- The top- and bottom-DIV contain one column each  and are not scrollable.
- The middle-DIV has to be height-restricted to play the trick:

e.g.

- Give the DIV a name and create a CSS-entry for it.
- height: 400px;  /* the height which fits best to your screen */
- overflow: auto; /* adds the scrollbar */

Comment: managed with DataTables. as it was the only option.